# Find out if the stream chunk is the last

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

When writing NodeJS Transform stream in transform function how can I know if the chunk is the last one or there is no any new chunk coming.

```js
_transform(chunk: any, encoding: string, callback: Function): void {
    // accumulating chunks here to buffer
    // so that I need to do some processing on the whole buffer
    // and I need to understand when to do that
}
```

So I need to know when the chunks coming to the Stream are over, to do some processing on the buffer composed of all the chunks and then push the processed data from the stream.

Comment: https://strongloop.com/strongblog/practical-examples-of-the-new-node-js-streams-api/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the `_transform` you can not figure out if there will be more data or not.

Depending on your use case you would either listen to the `end` event, or use `_flush`:

[Stream: transform._flush(callback)](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_transform_flush_callback):

> Custom Transform implementations may implement the `transform._flush()` method. This will be called when there is no more written data to be consumed, but before the `'end'` event is emitted signaling the end of the Readable stream.
>
> Within the `transform._flush()` implementation, the `readable.push()` method may be called zero or more times, as appropriate. The callback function must be called when the flush operation is complete.

Comment: Ok, but if I'm doing my post processing in `_flush`, stream never emits `end` event. Is it normal? Do I need to emit `end` event manually then? For example if I'm doing my post processing and then piping result of the stream to `http.ServerResponse` the loading never ends, but if I emit `end` event manually, everything is ok. Is it supposed to work that way, or I may have another problem?

Comment: I have written a "last chunk aware transform" and shared it below as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Example,

```js
const COUNTER_NULL_SYMBOL = Symbol('COUNTER_NULL_SYMBOL');

const Counter = () => {
  let data = COUNTER_NULL_SYMBOL;
  let counter = 1;
  let first = true;

  const counterStream = new Transform({

    objectMode: true,
    decodeStrings: false,
    highWaterMark: 1,

    transform(chunk, encoding, callback) {
      if (data === COUNTER_NULL_SYMBOL) {
        data = chunk;
        return callback();
      } else {
        this.push({data, counter, last: false, first});
        first = false;

        counter++;
        data = chunk;

        return callback();
      }
    },
  });

  counterStream._flush = function (callback) {
    if (data === COUNTER_NULL_SYMBOL) {
      return callback();
    } else {
      this.push({data, counter, last: true, first});
      return callback();
    }
  };

  return counterStream;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [through2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/through2#flushfunction)

```
fs.createReadStream('/tmp/important.dat')
  .pipe(through2(
    (chunk, enc, cb) => cb(null, chunk), // transform is a noop
    function (cb) { // FLUSH FUNCTION
      this.push('tacking on an extra buffer to the end');
      cb();
    }
  ))
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('/tmp/wut.txt'));
```

Comment: This helped me, don't need to keep a counter anymore :-)

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: WARNING DO NOT USE (I noticed that transform streams can still be pushed chunks after the source has ended or unpiped, I will see if I can come up with a solution and update this answer).

I have written a "last chunk aware transform" to demonstrate how to deal with this dilemma. Knowing at "chunk transform time" if the chunk is the last or not can be very useful (to check it afterwards on `_flush()` can be too late). This transform will also be compatible with streams that doesn't end it when done (unpipes instead), to try that out just un-comment the `// end: false` line. My code is license free, use it as you wish.

```js
import * as stream from 'node:stream'

// for this demo
class Source extends stream.Readable {
  #offset = 0; #size =  10
  _read(preferredSize) {
    if (this.#offset > this.#size) {
      this.push(null) // end stream
    } else {
      this.push(Buffer.from([this.#offset++]))
    }
  }
}

// for this demo (to inspect result)
class Output extends stream.Writable {
  _write(chunk, _encoding, callback) {
    console.log(chunk); callback()
  }
  _final(callback) {
    console.log('end'); callback()
  }
}

// last chunk aware transform
class Transform extends stream.Transform {
  #prevChunk
  #endOnUnpipe = true

  constructor() {
    super()
    this.on('unpipe', this.#onUnpipe)
  }

  _transform(chunk, _encoding, callback) {
    if (!this.#prevChunk) {
      this.#prevChunk = chunk
      callback()
    } else {
      this.#transform(this.#prevChunk, false, callback)
      this.#prevChunk = chunk
    }
    
  }

  #transform(chunk, isLast, callback) {
    if (isLast) chunk[0] = 0xFF
    this.push(chunk) // no change
    callback()
  }

  _flush(callback) {
    console.log('flush')
    this.#transform(this.#prevChunk, true, callback)
  }

  // if source did not end our transform
  #onUnpipe() {
    if (!this.writableEnded) {
      console.log('unpipe')
      if (this.#endOnUnpipe) {
        this.end() // will trigger _flush
      } else {
        this.#transform(this.#prevChunk, true, () => {})
      }
    }
  }
}

const
  source    = new Source(),
  transform = new Transform(),
  output    = new Output()

transform.pipe(output)
source.pipe(transform, {
  // end: false // whether to end transform or not at end of source
})
```

Usage notes: This works fine unless the stream can suddenly pause for a long time, then the transform of the last chunk will be delayed until it ends or more data is received. So be aware of this if that could be a problem for you.